# Sending json to asp.net mvc controller does make objects, but doesn't fill properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, facebook-javascript-sdk

So I want to post my jsondata that I've received from the facebook javascript SDK on my asp.NET webserver. The problem that I'm getting is that the facebookfriend-objects are being created (facebookfriendlist is populated), but aren't being filled (id = null, name = null for each object in the facebookfriendlist).

Json format

```
{"data":[{"name":"friend x","id":"integer here"},{"name":"friend y","id":"integer here"},...],"paging":{"next":"tokenXXX"}}
```

My jquery post (json is filled, I've printed the content into a div to check)

```
FB.api('/me/friends', function (response) {
        $("#friends").html(JSON.stringify(response));
        pb.progressbar("value", 66);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/MapMe/Retrieve',
            type: 'POST',
            data: response,
            accept: 'application/json',
            success: successFunc,
            error: errorFunc
        });

        function successFunc(data, status) {
            pb.progressbar("value", 100);
            //window.location.href = './App';
        }

        function errorFunc() {
            alert("Failed to get Data")
        }
    });
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Retrieve(FacebookFriendlist friends)
    {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(friends);
    return Json(new {status = true});
    }
```

My objectclasses

```
 public class FacebookFriendlist
    {
        public FacebookFriendlist()
        {
            data = new List<Facebookfriend>();
        }
        public IList<Facebookfriend> data { get; set; }
        public string paging { get; set; }
    }

    public class Facebookfriend
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Is the `paging` property empty as well?

Comment: I've completed the prop next, next was also null.
Code:
public class FacebookFriendlist
    {
        public FacebookFriendlist()
        {
            data = new List<Facebookfriend>();
        }
        public IList<Facebookfriend> data { get; set; }
        public paging paging { get; set; }
    }
    public class paging
    {
        public string next { get; set; }
    }

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you have `accept` in the jQuery `.ajax()` function, but it should be `accepts`, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/MapMe/Retrieve',
    type: 'POST',
    data: response,
    accepts: 'application/json',
    success: successFunc,
    error: errorFunc
});
```

---

Per jQuery `.ajax()` documentation:

> **accepts** (default: depends on DataType)
>
> The content type sent in the request header that tells the server what kind of response it will accept in return. If the accepts setting needs modification, it is recommended to do so once in the $.ajaxSetup() method.

Comment: The problem isn't posting with ajax. It's the conversion from json to c#-objects (http://grab.by/stfs). Thanks for the advice. Still looking for the answer

Answer (score 0):

To convert Json into c# you have to set traditional:true and dataType:"json" as below,

```
$.ajax({
      url: '/MapMe/Retrieve',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: "json",
      cache: false,
      traditional: true,
      data: data,
      success: function (data) {},
      error: function (data) {}
});
```

currently you are getting the default value of string.

Comment: it doesn't fill the FacebookFriendlistprop no more if I use "traditional: true,". It still works if I use value false on traditional, but the propertystringvalues are still null